# very ample line bundle on singular curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a singular reduced irreducible projective curve over $k$(algebraically closed).

How to show that if $X$ has arithmetic genus 1,then for any smooth (closed) point $p\in X$,$\mathcal{ O}(3p)$ is very ample?

(If $X$ is nonsingular,it is well-known.)

Comment: You may refer to this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404903001014